# How to fix my [HY093] error. It happends, when I send a form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I made a request to my database, but there is a problem

there is my database

[image]

and there is my class code

```
if (!empty(unserialize($data['copy-passport'])) && !empty(unserialize($data['photo']))) {
        $stmt = $this->connect->prepare("UPDATE requests SET status=:status, date=:date, firstname=:firstname, firstname-lat=:firstname-lat, lastname=:lastname, lastname-lat=:lastname-lat, middlename=:middlename, date-birth=:date-birth, phone=:phone, email=:email, region-home=:region-home, city=:city, street=:street, house=:house, apartment=:apartment, post-index=:post-index, photo=:photo, copy-passport=:copy-passport, delivery=:delivery, office=:office, region=:region WHERE id=:id");
        
        if ($stmt->execute(array(':status' => $data['status'], ':date' => strtotime($data['date']), ':firstname' => htmlspecialchars($data['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES), ':firstname-lat' => htmlspecialchars($data['firstname-lat'], ENT_QUOTES), ':lastname' => htmlspecialchars($data['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES), ':lastname-lat' => htmlspecialchars($data['lastname-lat'], ENT_QUOTES), ':middlename' => htmlspecialchars($data['middlename'], ENT_QUOTES), ':date-birth' => htmlspecialchars($data['date-birth'], ENT_QUOTES), ':email' => htmlspecialchars($data['email'], ENT_QUOTES), ':phone' => htmlspecialchars($data['phone'], ENT_QUOTES), ':region' => htmlspecialchars($data['region'], ENT_QUOTES), ':region-home' => htmlspecialchars($data['region-home'], ENT_QUOTES), ':street' => htmlspecialchars($data['street'], ENT_QUOTES), ':city' => htmlspecialchars($data['city'], ENT_QUOTES), ':house' => htmlspecialchars($data['house'], ENT_QUOTES), ':apartment' => htmlspecialchars($data['apartment'], ENT_QUOTES), ':post-index' => htmlspecialchars($data['post-index'], ENT_QUOTES), ':photo' => $data['photo'], ':copy-passport' => $data['copy-passport'], ':delivery' => htmlspecialchars($data['delivery'], ENT_QUOTES), ':office' => htmlspecialchars($data['office'], ENT_QUOTES), ':id' => $id))) {
            return true; 
        } else {
            return $stmt->errorInfo();
        }
```

And request page here

```
    <?php
if ($session->levelAccess() != 2) {
    $session->deleteSession();
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['abc'])) {$request1->updateRequest1($_GET['id'] ,$_POST, $_FILES);
        print_r($_POST);
        print_r($_FILES);
        // $engine->switchPartnerStatus($_GET['id'], $_POST['status']);
    }
    $request1_id = $_GET['id'];
    $stmt = $request1->connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `requests` WHERE id=:request1_id");
    if ($stmt->execute(array(':request1_id' => $request1_id))) {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
<!-- begin content -->
<main class="main">
    <div class="main__wrapper">
        <div class="main__title">
            <span class="main__title-text">Управление заявкой партнера</span>
        </div>
        <!-- begin content -->
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content__status">
                <span class="content__info-text"></span>
                <div class="content__order-block bg-yellow">
                    <span class="content__info-order">№ заявки: <span class="content__order-number"><?php echo $row['id'] ?></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form class="edit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="edit__block">
                    <input value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>"type="text" id="id" class="edit__input" name="id" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="request__line">
                        <p class="request__title-photo">Введите имя на английском языке/in english *</p>
                        <p for="firstname-lat" class="request__title">Имя (на английском языке/in english)</p>
                        <input type="text" class="request__info" id="firstname-lat" name="firstname-lat" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['firstname-lat'], ENT_QUOTES);; ?>" readonly="readonly">
                        <div class="btn__group">
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-main">Редактировать</span>
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-yes">Сохранить</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="request__line">
                        <p class="request__title-photo">Введите имя на русском языке/in russian *</p>
                        <p for="firstname"class="request__title">Имя (на русском языке/in russian)</p>
                        <input type="text" class="request__info" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" readonly="readonly" >
                        <div class="btn__group">
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-main">Редактировать</span>
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-yes">Сохранить</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="request__line">
                        <p class="request__title-photo">Введите фамилию на английском языке/in english *</p>
                        <p for="lastname-lat" class="request__title">Фамилия (на английском языке/in english)</p>
                        <input type="text" class="request__info" id="lastname-lat" name="lastname-lat" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['lastname-lat'], ENT_QUOTES);; ?>" readonly="readonly">
                        <div class="btn__group">
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-main">Редактировать</span>
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-yes">Сохранить</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="request__line">
                        <p class="request__title-photo">Введите фамилию на русском языке/in russian *</p>
                        <p for="lastname" class="request__title">Фамилия (на русском языке/in russian)</p>
                        <input type="text" class="request__info" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" readonly="readonly" >
                        <div class="btn__group">
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-main">Редактировать</span>
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-yes">Сохранить</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="request__line">
                        <p class="request__title-photo">Введите отчество на русском языке/in russian *</p>
                        <p for="middlename" class="request__title">Отчество (на русском языке/in russian)</p>
                        <input type="text" class="request__info" id="middlename" name="middlename" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['middlename'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" readonly="readonly" >
                        <div class="btn__group">
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-main">Редактировать</span>
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-yes">Сохранить</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="request__line">
                        <p class="request__title-photo">Введите дату рождения *</p>
                        <p for="date-birth" class="request__title">Дата рождения</p>
                        <input type="text" class="request__info" id="date-birth" name="date-birth" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['date-birth'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>" readonly="readonly" >
                        <div class="btn__group">
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-main">Редактировать</span>
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-yes">Сохранить</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="request__line">
                        <p class="request__title-photo">Введите ваш телефон, пример: +70123456789 *</p>
                        <p for="phone" class="request__title">Телефон</p>
                        <input type="text" class="request__info" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo $row['phone']; ?>" readonly="readonly">
                        <div class="btn__group">
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-main">Редактировать</span>
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-yes">Сохранить</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="request__line">
                        <p class="request__title-photo">Введите ваш email, пример: example@mail.com *</p>
                        <p for="email" class="request__title">E-mail</p>
                        <input type="text" class="request__info" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" readonly="readonly">
                        <div class="btn__group">
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-main">Редактировать</span>
                            <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-yes">Сохранить</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="request__line">
                    <p class="request__title-photo">Выберите название вашего региона проживания *</p>
                    <p for="region-home" class="request__title">Регион проживания</p>
                    <select name="region-home" id="region-home" class="form__region" >
                        <option name="region-home" id="region-home" value="<?php echo $row['region-home'];?>" class="form__region-option" selected><?php echo $geo->getRegionNameById($row['region-home']);?></option>
                        <?php
                        $geo = new Geo;
                        $regions = $geo->getAllRegions();
                        foreach ($regions as $key => $value) {
                            echo '<option name="region-home" id="region-home" value="'.$value['region_id'].'" class="form__region-option">'.$value['name'].'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <!--<script>
                    function activatePostInfo(value){
                        switch(value) {
                            case "1":
                                document.getElementById("selfDelivery").setAttribute("class", "delivery-blockd");
                                document.getElementById("nonSelfDelivery").setAttribute("class", "delivery-blockh");
                                break;
                            case "2":
                                document.getElementById("selfDelivery").setAttribute("class", "delivery-blockh");
                                document.getElementById("nonSelfDelivery").setAttribute("class", "delivery-blockd");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                </script>-->
                <div class="request__line">
                    <p class="request__title-photo">Выберите тип и адрес доставки *</p>
                    <p for="delivery" lass="request__title">Доставка</p>
                    <div class="form__input ">
                        <select name="delivery" id="delivery" class="form__delivery" >.
                            <?php if ($row['delivery'] == '1') {
                                    echo '<option name="delivery" id="delivery" value="1" selected>Самовывоз</option>';
                                    echo '<option name="delivery" id="delivery" value="2">Доставка почтой</option>';
                                } elseif ($row['delivery'] == '2') {
                                    echo '<option name="delivery" id="delivery" value="1">Самовывоз</option>';
                                    echo '<option name="delivery" id="delivery" value="2" selected>Доставка почтой</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="request__line">
                    <p for="office"><label>Город для самовывоза:</label></p>
                    <select name="office" id="office" class="form__delivery">
                        <option name="office" id="office" value="1" class="form__region-option">Выберете город</option>
                        <option name="office" id="office" value="Москва" class="form__region-option">Москва</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="request__line">
                    <p for="region"><label for="sip_buy_city">Регион</label></p>
                    <div class="form__input ">
                        <select name="region" id="sip_buy_region" class="sip_buy_region">
                            <option name="region" id="region" value="0" selected="selected">Выберите регион..</option>
                            <?php
                            $regions = $geo->getAllRegions();
                            foreach ($regions as $key => $value) {
                                echo '<option name="region" id="region" value="'.$value['region_id'].'" class="form__region-option">'.$value['name'].'</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="request__line">
                    <p for="city"><label for="sip_buy_city">Город (населенный пункт)</label></p>
                    <div name="city" id="city" class="form__input ">
                        <select name="city" id="sip_buy_city" class="sip_buy_city">
                            <option name="city" id="city" value="0" selected="selected">Нет данных..</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="request__line">
                    <p class="request__title-photo">Введите название вашей улицы *</p>
                    <p for="street" class="request__title">Улица</p>
                    <input type="text" class="request__info" name="street" id="street" value="<?php echo $row['street']; ?>" readonly="readonly">
                    <div class="btn__group">
                        <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-main">Редактировать</span>
                        <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-yes">Сохранить</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="request__line">
                    <p class="request__title-photo">Введите цифру вашего дома *</p>
                    <p for="house" class="request__title">Дом</p>
                    <input type="text" class="request__info" name="house" id="house" value="<?php echo $row['house']; ?>" readonly="readonly">
                    <div class="btn__group">
                        <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-main">Редактировать</span>
                        <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-yes">Сохранить</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="request__line">
                    <p class="request__title-photo">Введите номер вашей квартиры *</p>
                    <p for="apartment"class="request__title">Квартира</p>
                    <input type="text" class="request__info" name="apartment" id="apartment" value="<?php echo $row['apartment']; ?>" readonly="readonly">
                    <div class="btn__group">
                        <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-main">Редактировать</span>
                        <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-yes">Сохранить</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="request__line">
                    <p class="request__title-photo">Введите ваш индекс *</p>
                    <p for="post-index" class="request__title">Индекс</p>
                    <input type="text" class="request__info" name="post-index" id="post-index" value="<?php echo $row['post-index']; ?>" readonly="readonly">
                    <div class="btn__group">
                        <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-main">Редактировать</span>
                        <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-yes">Сохранить</span>
                    </div>
                </div>      
                <div class="request__line">
                    <p class="request__title-photo">При добавлении новых фотографий старые фото будут удалены. Допускаются файлы в формате .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png, размером не более 3 мегабайт*</p>
                    <p class="request__title-photo">Максимальный размер фотографии не должен превышать 400 x 400 пикселей*</p>
                    <p for="photo" class="request__title">Фотография</p>
                    <label for="photo" class="file-uploader__title">Загрузить</label>
                    <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" class="file__input">
                    <div class="file-pre">
                        <?php echo $image->showImages($row['photo'], 'photo/'.$row['id']) ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="request__line">
                    <p class="request__title-photo">При добавлении новых фотографий старые фото будут удалены. Допускаются файлы в формате .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png, размером не более 3 мегабайт*</p>
                    <p class="request__title-photo">Максимальный размер фотографии не должен превышать 400 x 400 пикселей*</p>
                    <p for="copy-passport" class="request__title">Фотографии паспорта</p>
                    <label for="copy-passport" class="file-uploader__title">Загрузить</label>
                    <input type="file" id="copy-passport" name="copy-passport" class="file__input">
                    <div class="file-pre">
                        <?php echo $image->showImages($row['copy-passport'], 'passport/'.$row['id']) ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="request__line">
                    <p class="request__title-photo">Выберите один из статусов заявки *</p>
                    <p for="status" class="request__title">Статус заявки</p>
                    <select name="status" id="status" class="request__select">
                        <option name="status" id="status" value="1" class="request__option" <?php if($row['status'] == '1') {echo 'selected';}?>>Новая заявка</option>
                        <option name="status" id="status" value="2" class="request__option" <?php if($row['status'] == '2') {echo 'selected';}?>>В обработке</option>
                        <option name="status" id="status" value="3" class="request__option" <?php if($row['status'] == '3') {echo 'selected';}?>>Завершенная</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="request__line">
                    <p class="request__title-photo">Введите дату заявки *</p>
                    <p for="date" class="request__title">Дата</p>
                    <input type="text" class="request__info" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo $row['date']; ?>" readonly="readonly">
                    <div class="btn__group">
                        <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-main">Редактировать</span>
                        <span class="btn__edit btn__edit-yes">Сохранить</span>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="request__line">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit2" class="btn__edit btn__final bg-grey" value="вернуться назад">
                    <input type="submit" name="abc" class="btn__edit btn__final bg-green-1" value="Сохранить">
                </div> 
                </div>  
            </form>
        </div>
```

it seems that I have a mistake in some POST request option. Don't know where my mistake is. I changed submit button name, and it fixed the problem, but error still appears. Don't know where the mistake is. Pls explain, where I was wrong.

here is an error code:

Array ( [0] => HY093 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVP9D.png) => [2] => )

Comment: __Provide error text__, also read about escaping `-` as it is __minus__ and not a dash.

Comment: Array ( [0] => HY093 1 => [2] => )  did you mean it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with changing some dashes and minuses, added some ' where it was nessesary,

thx to @u-mulder